# Unable to use the proper selector to add a class to an li tag

Tags: jquery, html

This is my HTML .

```
<div id="activeui4" class="activateUiHTML" data-role="collapsible">
   <div class="prd-items-detials">
      <ul>
         <li class="head">
            <form>
            </form>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here i am trying to dynamically add a class to the  tag .

I tried it this way

```
var id_attr_val = 4;

$("#activeui"+id_attr_val+".activateUiHTML").find(".prd-items-detials").find("ul").next("li").addClass("headActive");
```

There is no exception in the browser console, but the class is not getting relecting.

could anybody please help .

Unable to use the proper selector to add a class

Comment: i think there is a typo, - the class is not getting _what_ ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#activeui"+id_attr_val+".activateUiHTML")
.find(".prd-items-detials")
.find("ul li") //not next li, it's in ul
.addClass("headActive");
```

Or use children instead of next:

```
$("#activeui"+id_attr_val+".activateUiHTML")
.find(".prd-items-detials")
.find("ul")
.children("li")
.addClass("headActive");
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, whenn you add some explaination to your intension.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
 $("div[id^='activeui'][class='activateUiHTML']").find(".prd-items-detials")
```

.find("ul li").addClass("headActive");

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4d9p4rw7/)

[Update Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4d9p4rw7/1/)